# Moving a Label with mouseMove Windows Forms

Tags: c#, mousemove

I've been trying to make a label follow wherever the mouse is along the x-axis.
The label only moves when the mouse hovers on to the label and does not move smoothly how it should.

```
  private void label1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int maxX = this.Width - label1.Width;
        if (e.X < maxX)
            label1.Left = e.X;
    }
```

Is there something I might have missed ?

Comment: Please add to your question which GUI technology you use: WPF, WinForms, etc.

Comment: Assuming you are developing for WinForms: Since you are using `MouseMove` event of Label control, this event is fired whenever mouse hovers inside client area of label, to make it work in entire form you should use Form's `MouseMove` event.

Comment: Thanks @raidensan It works perfectly now!